# How to manage email accounts in centos 6 and roundcube

Tags: centos, mail-server, roundcube, centos6

I have setup roundcube on my centos 6 server. Now want to create a admin panel so I can manage users. I could not found a way to install admin like iredadmin on already running server.
I have courier mail server.
Can any one give a better suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

PostfixAdmin. Perfect solution. :)